# How to implement page control in tableview cell ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I implement tableview cell programmatically and swipe view also attach this.
This tableview cell shows an user profile name and images,every image of user profile has its own like,comment or description.

-If a user profile contain more than one image so he can swipe and view another image,its working fine.

-But the problem is that,the like,comment or description of that image is not been updated,second image also shows the like,comment of first image.

-I want to implement that when a user profile contains more than one image when he swipe to view another image,he should also see the like or comment of other image,but swipe like a page control.

-This is my swipe view code which i implemented please see and tell about that what could i changed so my problem is fixed thanks in advance.

```
- (UIView *)swipeView:(SwipeView *)swipeView viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (!view)
    {
        view = [[UIView alloc]init];
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,  [gclass getWidth: 748],[gclass getHeight: 430]);
        else
            view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,  [gclass getWidth: 310],[gclass getHeight: 310]);
        UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] init];

        img.frame=view.frame;
        img.tag=2;
        [view addSubview:img];


    }



UIImageView *img=[view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDictionary *dict=[swipeView.gallery objectAtIndex:index];
    [img sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat :@"%@%@%@",defaulturl,event_gallery_small,[dict valueForKey:@"filepath"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"image_default.png"]];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: If you want to see my tableview cell code then please tell me then i will also upload this.thanks

Answer (score 1):

you also declare that image description and comment in viewForItemAtIndex section. now you declare image only in that code.

Comment: Dear i also try this but couldn't working when i scroll my table view description and comment again updated,and i also remove code that i set description,comment in cellForRowAtIndexPath but still updatinh i couldn't know why its updating.